# reading .csv in matlab, string seems to be non existent?

Tags: matlab, csv

I am trying to read a .csv file in matlab and saving it as .txt. but it seems that when i print the lines in my .txt file, the line is nothing:

```
fid1 = fopen('input.csv');
fid = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
tline = fgetl(fid1);
tline = strrep(tline,'remove','')
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', tline);
fclose(fid1);
fclose(fid);
```

when i open the file afterwards the file is empty
if i convert the .csv file to .txt using excell there is no problem.

how do i easily convert the .csv data into .txt?

i can't do it manually because i have hundreds of .csv files

Comment: The suffix `.txt`says that file is (any) text. Suffix `.csv` says, taht file is comma separated data structure. Both have same encoding; if you **do not need** to process the data and you want `.csv` to be `.txt` **only**, just rename it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not processing every line of your csv file (if the first line is empty it explains your empty txt files).

```
fid1 = fopen('test.csv');
fid = fopen('output.txt', 'w');

tline = fgetl(fid1);
while ischar(tline)
  tline = strrep(tline,'remove','');
  fprintf(fid, '%s\n', tline);
  tline = fgetl(fid1);  
end

fclose(fid1);
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: The first line of the file is when i call it using fgetl
ÿþM A K E :   V O L V O

i can also get matlab to display each line just before i asl it to print it to the file, but the file is still empty. Might it be due to some formatting of the .csv file?

Comment: Could you upload a sample file so that I can check how does it run on my system? I hope I can reproduce your error, otherwise I don't have any ideas what is wrong.